# Way to inspect element and see the PHP page it's on?

Tags: find, web-inspector, inspect, code-inspection

Is there a way to inspect an element and see the PHP page (template file) that element is coming from?

For example, using Google Chrome's developer tools I can see which .CSS page any element is using. I'd like to do the same to quickly find the .PHP files I need to edit.

**EDIT:**
I realize that simply doing this with any browser tool could be a big security issue. So, is there some sort of local debug tool, or a script I could install that would allow me to do this while the debug=true for example?

Comment: Nope. you can't inspect PHP code using any browser. Because after rendering to HTML only the page will be delivered to browser. So you can't inspect any element except HTML.

Comment: That makes sense. There has got to be some sort of script I could write that would perhaps 'print' the file name of each page/template that gets loaded when I navigate to a page, right? Obviously I would only want that to run in development. But Could something like that work?

Comment: Well I never heard about that type of tool. If you get it, please let me know :)
It will be helpful for me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse you might want to take a look at [this article](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/HowToSetupDevelopmentEnvironmentWindows). You can actually follow the flow by stepping into the code. Other than that you might want to take a look at [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/products/studio3). I haven't used it much for PHP, but for rails it gives you a lot of hints - so I imagine it to work well for PHP too.